# clone git repository via active FTP

Tags: git, ftp, clone

I'm a branch office worker and have uploaded my existing repo to the ftp server at my company's central office. The central office is using Microsoft's ftp server. I have no access to install anything on the server and was only able to connect/browse to the ftp server using a real ftp client that supports active mode ftp.

I have tried cloning with the following command lines:

```
git clone ftp://companyDomain\username@ftp.company.com/project.repo/.git 
git clone ftp://username@company.com@ftp.company.com/project.repo/.git
git clone ftp://username%40company.com@ftp.company.com/project.repo/.git
git clone ftp://username:password@ftp.company.com/project.repo/.git
```

And I get the following error message:

> error: Failed connect to `ftp.company.com:21`; No error while accessing
>   `ftp://companyDomain\username@ftp.company.com/project.repo/.git/info/refs`
>   fatal: HTTP request failed

When entering the above commands I immediately get prompted for my password. I enter the password, some time passes and then I received the above error message.

To be completely clear I'm am NOT looking to push the head version of my source to an FTP server for deployment, so things like git-ftp, https://github.com/resmo/git-ftp, don't help me out at all. What I want to do is have my repo on the ftp server and everyone on my very small team be able to push/fetch changes to the repo on the ftp server.

Does git support active FTP?
What's going on?

Thanks, 
Chris

Comment: You might want to check the answers given here: Git repository on ftp server (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5141205/git-repository-on-ftp-server)

Comment: Already reviewed that answer and the related postings

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do they use the default FTP port? If they don't, you need to declare it like so:

```
git clone ftp://username:password@ftp.company.com:PORTHERE/project.repo/.git
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
git clone ftp://username:password@ftp.company.com/project.repo/.git
```

Comment: Sorry, that was my one idea. Looking at the docs, git doesn't support FTP, so I'm surprised you got as far as you did.

Comment: I appreciate the help. From this answer it does look like ftp is supported: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5709192/git-clone-over-ftps/5709229#5709229

Answer (score 0):

I tried also all FTP examples here, none was working. Since my server pc is a linux machine I installed git on it and then can clone be done use:

```
git clone username:servername:/folder1/folder2/repoFolder.git
```

Then you will be asked for password.
If no git is installed on server you will get:

```
sh: git-upload-pack: not found
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```