# How to clone git repository via SourceTree using ftp account?

Tags: git, ftp, atlassian-sourcetree

my domain: **bs.com**
main ftp account: **bs**

i set up a new ftp account:

New FTP account:
login: **annejulie@bs.com**
password: **password**
port: **21**
 *(the number of port i get from the program i use to coonnect to ftp account, in my case "Cyberduck")*

full path to git repository: **home/bs/git/annejulie.bs.com.git**

I do not know if it is important, but new FTP account has an access to followed path **/home/bs/domains/annejulie.bs.com**

My source URL to clone git repository:

```
ftp://annejulie@bs.com:password@bs.com:21/home/bs/git/annejulie.bs.com.git
```

when i pass my source url i get an error:

```
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
fatal: unable to access 
'ftp://annejulie@bs.com:password@bs.com:21/home/bs/git/annejulie.bs.com.git/': 
Could not resolve host: bs.com:annejulie@bs.com
```

I read this article [clone git repository via active FTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7919736/clone-git-repository-via-active-ftp)
but it didn't work for me. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Have you considered using GitHub or another "proper" git provider instead of self-hosting it via FTP?

Comment: i got an error again

fatal: unable to access 
    'ftp://annejulie%40bs.com:password@bs.com:21/home/bs/git/annejulie.bs.com.git/': 
    Server denied you to change to the given directory


What is still wrong? Thanks for Your reply.

Comment: FTP is usually chrooted, so you most likely don't need to specify `/home/bs` in the path (it really depends on the config of the FTP). Check with a FTP client which path it uses for the repo.

Comment: What does it mean that server denied me to change to the given directory? Denied me to get to this files and copy a repo? I do not know exactly, what should i do for now. I mean how to manually ftping into my server and seeing what directories are available for my ftp account?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to URL-encode the @ in the username (%40):

```
ftp://annejulie%40bs.com:password@bs.com:21/home/bs/git/annejulie.bs.com.git
```